# Calcinai xero-php pass config once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to figure out how to get started with this package correctly. I've installed it via Composer, and can get it working using some of the instructions in the readme, but at this stage I am having to pass the config variables every time like so:

```
$config = ['oauth' => [ 
             'consumer_key'     => 'MYCONSUMERKEY',
             'consumer_secret'  => 'MYSECRETKEY',
             'rsa_private_key'  => 'file:///pathtokey',
             'rsa_public_key'   => 'file:///pathtopubkey'
          ];

$xero = new \XeroPHP\Application\PrivateApplication($config);
```

This seems to fly in the face of everything I've done with Laravel before. Any packages I've used in the past have come with config files to configure and a facade, so I'm not sure how to progress here to set the config once and then load this package as and where I need it with the stored config.

I'd like to learn what to do in these kind of instances.

Comment: You could use [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) with your custom config files [Accessing Configuration Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Comment: @SeánMcCabe Is there something missing from my answer for it to get accepted?

Comment: Nope, thought I had done it, apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the difference between a general PHP library and a Laravel-specific wrapper. A general PHP library like XeroPHP doesn't know (or care) what PHP framework you're using - its only required dependencies are a particular version of PHP and some PHP extensions. What you're asking about is a Laravel "package", and the [Laravel documentation on packages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages) is pretty good if you want to get a headstart at writing your own.

You can choose to write your own wrapper locally in your project, or create your own package that wraps around XeroPHP. You could then publish that package on [Packalyst](https://packalyst.com/) and [Packagist](https://packagist.org) to make it available to the Laravel community at large.

In this case you're in luck and you don't need to - [Amo Chohan has done it for you](https://packalyst.com/packages/package/drawmyattention/xerolaravel)! You just need to require the Laravel package instead of XeroPHP directly.

As a sidebar, I can see you also [asked the author](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php/issues/319) of the library about this - generally a good idea to be as specific as possible in terms of the framework you're asking about if you want help from the package directly. You could also ping other authors (respectfully!) on github that regularly contribute to a lot of Laravel plugins if you want some more help.

Comment: xerolaravel should do the trick if he's using `xero-php ^1.6` (according to the updated composer.json file)

Comment: @Leith I've attempted to use this one, and yer it is exactly what I want, but the problem being, using the facade I cannot find how to do a make, i.e. make Contact, rather than just a loadByGUID. It has an example of using the IOC, and again, cannot get that working either.

Comment: @SeánMcCabe that's a slightly different problem - the wrapper allows you to set up the config once and use a facade/service provider (the OP). The repo readme.md has a pretty good example on creating a contact, it's just in the middle of creating an invoice - if you strip out all the other invoice-related stuff (but keep the IoC container) that should work? i.e keep everything for `$xero` and `$contact` in the example, ditch the rest.

Comment: Happy to [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157316/room-for-leith-and-sean-mccabe) if you prefer.

Comment: @Leith, I am using the same package but I am having an error. it says `Undefined variable: config`

Comment: @SarahMalik are you using the same code example from the OP with XeroPHP directly, or `xerolaravel`?